# I would like to track the RSI indicator from Tradingview and get a notification when it reaches certain level(s)

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, tradingview-api

as I wrote in the title, I would like to track the rsi indicator on tradingview and get a notif if it hits certain level or levels. The problem is i started learning python just a week ago and have no idea where to even start with this. Ive seen some videos on something called web scraping but really i have no idea what that is or if it would work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can start by calculating the RSI indicator according to TradingView charts' data.

Here is a Python implementation of the current RSI indicator version in TradingView:

https://github.com/lukaszbinden/rsi_tradingview/blob/main/rsi.py

After you have RSI value, you can easily apply differents kinds of monitoring.